# Integrating messenger to an existing website

Tags: jquery, python, api, gmail, yahoo-messenger

For an existing website and the users in it,how to integrate a chat application like yahoo or gmail or any other with minimum code changes.

Comment: do you want to chat between the users, or from the user to a representative of the site?

Comment: the users are divided into groups.And the users of a group should be able to chat with each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ajax IM](http://ajaxim.com/) looks very good for this.

Alternatively, maybe something like [PHP121](http://www.php121.com/)?

These are both instant messenger style chat systems.  If you're looking for something more like a chatroom, I have used [Ajax Chat](https://blueimp.net/ajax/) successfully in the past.

I think you'll need a fair bit of code changes however you approach this, if you want to support your existing groups of users.